# Prompt changed in my terminal

Tags: macos

I recently installed Yosemite. A couple of days back it changed my prompt from `Macbook:~ adnan` to `Mac-e80688dc7a26:~ adnan`

I have no idea why did it happen and how do I restore it.

Comment: This is a result of DHCP. I've closed this as a duplicate, but please edit the post if you can't make use of the linked answers to solve your issue. Explain what about the linked answers doesn't make sense or apply :-) The one time fix is to open Sharing system preferences and rename the Mac to what you want it to be.

Comment: running `sudo scutil –-set HostName MacBookPro` is not doing anything. It shows `>` prompt on other line